# MySQL server configuration issues

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

As my topic says, the max_allowed_packet variable is not working.
I have a project in eclipse which loads csv-files up and store them into a mysql database through a servlet. For files smaller than 1M it works fine.
But my file is 95Mb big, and i have increase the 'max_allow_packet' variable in the my.ini file in the section [mysqld] up to 500M.
But it doesen't work. Eclipse gives my the same error.
Please take a look at this two pictures:

ECLIPSE

[image]

my.ini

[mysqld]
....

[image]

Thanks for help

*****EDIT*****

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (190104490 > 26214400). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3540)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
at upload.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And this is the main-code where the file is upload and then store in mysql:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    Part part = request.getPart("file");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = part.getInputStream();
    CSV csv = new CSV();


    String name = null;
    String header = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    if(header.contains("filename"))
    {
        name = header.substring(header.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, header.length()).replace("\"", "");
    }


    int i = 0;
    while((i = in.read()) != -1 )
    {
        baos.write(i);
    }
    csv.setCsvFile(baos.toByteArray());
    csv.setName(name);
    baos.flush();

    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {           
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loadcsvup","*****","*******");        
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO loadcsvup.csvfiles (csv_name,file) VALUES (?,?)");
        stmt.setString(1, csv.getName());
        stmt.setBytes(2, csv.getCsvFile());         
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        stmt.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

***** EDIT 2 *****

Ok, now i have set the varibale also in de [client] section of the my.ini file. Seems to be work.
But now i got this error code:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: The size of   BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
at upload.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've set the varibable like this:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1GB
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
```

Comment: Please add the error text instead of a picture to make it findable by search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check points**

- Have you restarted mysql service after changing my.ini?
- Run query `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'` and see the value. It should be 500MB (Equal bytes)
- If the above query does not return 500M, then try running `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 500 * 1024 * 1024`. Then repeat step 2.
- If value is shown as 500 M repeat your file upload.

If still problem persists, then it could be like mysql is looking at different variable.

Comment: with your answer i got the problem to work. I have reinstall the whole mysql database, and then it works. Thanks